# Recursion factorial program confusion in C

Tags: c

```
int factorial(int n); 
int main() 
{ 
    int n;  
    printf("Enter an positive integer: "); 
    scanf("%d",&n); 
    printf("Factorial of %d = %ld", n, factorial(n)); 
    return 0; 
} 
int factorial(int n) 
{ 
   if(n!=1) 
        return n*factorial(n-1); 
}
```

Please explain how this program is working. I applied a for loop after if statement in factorial function but how this is working.

Comment: Quick suggestion: Please format your code using the "{}" in the question editor's toolbar. Thanks!

Comment: what does your `factorial` return when n==1?

Comment: It's Undefined Behaviour. There's no `return` for the base case.

Comment: The key issue is either not having all warnings enabled or using a sub-standard compiler.  As `int factorial()` has a path that does not return a value, a good compiler would warn about that saving you time. It would also warn about `main()`, `printf("Factorial of %d = %ld", n, factorial(n));`.

Comment: usually you will not come across loops in recursion. only base condition and recursive calls.@Must

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion Has the factorial example

Answer (score 0):

```
int factorial(int n){
    if(n==1)
       return 1;
    return n*(factorial(n-1));
```

}

This is correct :) I think that your code shouldn't compile because the function factorial(int n) has no defined return statement!